# Rendering transparent meshes in LibGDX

Tags: opengl-es, transparency, libgdx

Building open this tutorial - https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera I have constructed a class for generating polygon meshes. But i cannot figure out how to render semi transparency, even though the mesh in the tutorial takes a color object with an alpha channel.

I am rendering with squareMesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4); This is the code used for initializing the mesh

```
if (squareMesh == null) {
    squareMesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 4, 
                 new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position,    3, "a_position"),
                 new VertexAttribute(Usage.ColorPacked, 4, "a_color"));

    squareMesh.setVertices(new float[] {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(128, 0, 0, 255),
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(192, 0, 0, 255),
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(192, 0, 0, 255),
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0, Color.toFloatBits(255, 0, 0, 255) });   
    squareMesh.setIndices(new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 3});
}
```

Comment: What else are you rendering?  (What do you expect to see through your transparent mesh?).  Also, `255` is fully opaque, so presumably you set the alpha to something lower?

Comment: Yes the alpha value does not change anything, I would expect to see the background through the mesh. for example: with a white mesh and a black background I would expect to see a grey square if the alpha values were set to 128.

Comment: I had the same problem and resolved it by using 2 `Color` objects. The first is the desired color, the other is just a temporary color where I put all values of desired color multiplied by its alpha, and then I update the vertices of the `Mesh` with it. This is a bit tricky/dirty, so if you find a *clean* solution let me know please.

Comment: @miNde - wouldn't that just render a mesh with colors closer to black instead of actually blending the color with the background?

Comment: Ew... That's true. I didn't notice that because it was a test and the background was black. Maybe you should open a ticket on the issue tracker of LibGDX on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many of the Libgdx infrastructure classes enable blending automatically.  If you're drawing meshes yourself, you will probably need to turn blending on manually:

```
Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); // Or GL20
```

Comment: Nothing really changed, would you happen to know where i could read more on this or how this should be correctly implemented?

Comment: Maybe make the blending function explicit too?  `Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`  This is mostly regular OpenGL as wrapped by LWJGL, so its not really covered in the Libgdx docs (AFAICT).  If that doesn't fix it, please show the code that clears the screen and maybe try rendering two meshes to see if you can blend them.

Comment: I initialise with `Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0, 0.1f, 1);` and clear the screen with `Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` and two meshes with alpha set to 0 changes nothing.

Comment: I found that this was the solution, but if rendering through a spriteBatch, for some reason you have to disable blending for the sprite batch for the mesh transparency to take effect

Answer (score 1):

I found that `ModelBatch.begin(...)` will disable Blending by calling `Gdx.gl.glDisable(GL20.GL_BLEND)`. So make sure to enable blending AFTER calling `ModelBatch.begin()`.

```
modelBatch.begin(camera); // resets Blending to false
// enable Blending
Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
// draw mesh
mesh.render(shader, GL20.GL_TRIANGLES);
modelBatch.end();
```

There is also an equivalent method to enable blending in ModelBatch

```
modelBatch.getRenderContext().setBlending(true, GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```